# iOS upgrade to twitter api 1.1

Tags: ios, api, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I currently have a bunch of apps that go and make simple anonymous calls to the twitter API, and grab several differing timelines.  Obviously, twitter is changing things up with 1.1, and is demanding authenticated calls using oauth.  Does that mean each of my users need a token (their own account) to do call, or do I need one app token for all of them?  Should I be using the twitter api included with iOS 5?  Note:  These are not the user's timeline...just several news feeds on twitter.  Am a bit confused.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, I struggled with this myself.

You can use Twitter API client via PHP and then json_encode the user timeline you want and parse it. This is not the best practice, but is a work around I had to do for an app on which I wanted to only display tweets no other action was need, like getting links, retweets, etc.

hope this serves.